# How to fix fetchInfo error in using Raydium sdk

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, raydium

Please let me know how to fix this error or how to swap SPL token with code in Raydium.

- This is my code.
  const poolInfo = await Liquidity.fetchInfo({ connection, poolKeys });
  "Liquidity is Raydium sdk function. poolKeys is publicKey type."
- This is error.
  tx failed => Error: simulate log not match keyword (argument="keyword"), value="GetPoolData"), code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, module=common/web3, version=1.1.0-beta.1)
  at W.makeError (logger.ts:216:1)
  at W.throwError (logger.ts:228:1)
  at W.throwArgumentError (logger.ts:232:1)
  at W.assertArgument (logger.ts:246:1)
  at Wt (web3.ts:252:1)
  at async qe.fetchMultipleInfo (liquidity.ts:1622:1)
  at async qe.fetchInfo (liquidity.ts:1566:1)
  at async calcAmountOut (raydium.js:45:1)
  at async tradeContext.js:191:1 : this is my own script.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your poolKeys parameter doesn't match the fetchInfo input.

You might want to check how you get your parameters.

Here's my approach for your reference.

```
const {
    Liquidity,
    Market,
    findProgramAddress,
    LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4,
    MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3,
    SPL_MINT_LAYOUT,
} = require('@raydium-io/raydium-sdk')

async function formatAmmKeysById(id) {
    const account = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(id))

    if (account === null) throw Error(' get id info error ')
    const info = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data)

    const marketId = info.marketId
    const marketAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(marketId)
    if (marketAccount === null) throw Error(' get market info error')
    const marketInfo = MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.decode(marketAccount.data)

    const lpMint = info.lpMint
    const lpMintAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(lpMint)
    if (lpMintAccount === null) throw Error(' get lp mint info error')
    const lpMintInfo = SPL_MINT_LAYOUT.decode(lpMintAccount.data)

    return {
        id,
        baseMint: info.baseMint.toString(),
        quoteMint: info.quoteMint.toString(),
        lpMint: info.lpMint.toString(),
        baseDecimals: info.baseDecimal.toNumber(),
        quoteDecimals: info.quoteDecimal.toNumber(),
        lpDecimals: lpMintInfo.decimals,
        version: 4,
        programId: account.owner.toString(),
        authority: Liquidity.getAssociatedAuthority({ programId: account.owner }).publicKey.toString(),
        openOrders: info.openOrders.toString(),
        targetOrders: info.targetOrders.toString(),
        baseVault: info.baseVault.toString(),
        quoteVault: info.quoteVault.toString(),
        withdrawQueue: info.withdrawQueue.toString(),
        lpVault: info.lpVault.toString(),
        marketVersion: 3,
        marketProgramId: info.marketProgramId.toString(),
        marketId: info.marketId.toString(),
        marketAuthority: Market.getAssociatedAuthority({ programId: info.marketProgramId, marketId: info.marketId }).publicKey.toString(),
        marketBaseVault: marketInfo.baseVault.toString(),
        marketQuoteVault: marketInfo.quoteVault.toString(),
        marketBids: marketInfo.bids.toString(),
        marketAsks: marketInfo.asks.toString(),
        marketEventQueue: marketInfo.eventQueue.toString(),
        lookupTableAccount: PublicKey.default.toString()
    }
}

const targetPoolInfo = await formatAmmKeysById("target_pool_address");
const poolKeys = jsonInfo2PoolKeys(targetPoolInfo)
```

you can also check [this](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo) link for more info.